# How to make the content in full height of the jQuery tabs container?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have a jQuery tabs ctrl, each tab has a textarea in it. I want to maximize the tabs within its parent div, so I set the tabs div to 100% width/height by css, it works. but how can I maximize the textarea in it?

Objective: tabs fill up the parent div, textarea fill up the parent tabs, when parent div is resized, tabs and textarea would be resized, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tabs = $('tabsSelector');
var $parentPane = $('parentSelector')
var newHeight = $parentPane.height() - 10;
$tabs.height(newHeight);
var navHeight = $tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav:first").height();
$tabs.children(".ui-tabs-panel").height(newHeight - navHeight);
```